# read file dynamically and don't use unnecessary memory in C

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I need to write a program which read a text file for example:

```
Peter
Jack
John
```

In here main aim is dont's use extra memory. And so i wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    FILE *file_pointer; 

    file_pointer = fopen("humans.txt","r");

    value = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)); // I think its most possible 
                                    //writing with don't use extra memory

    while( fscanf(file_pointer,"%s", value) != EOF ){
        printf("Name: %s Size of name: %d",value,strlen(value));
    }

}
```

when i run with some text file sample, there was no problem but when i run with valgrind, it gave me this error:

```
==22726== Invalid read of size 4
==22726==    at 0x4EA21BD: __isoc99_fscanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==22726==    by 0x400716: main (in /mnt//ogr/bxxxxx/a)
==22726==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

So, how can i write this code efficiently, how can i allocate memory don't use extra memory to read text file ?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is crucial and marks the end of the string. It also means that a string of N characters needs space for N+1 to fit the terminator. Since `scanf` will read at least one character and then add the terminator, it will write at least two bytes to the memory pointed to by the argument. If you don't know the size, you need to read one character at a time, and reallocate as needed.

Comment: I have forgotten this, thanks to remark